# How can I find the package for an include file?

Tags: c, linux, include

How can I know what linux package has a certain .h file ? Specifically I need the package for

```
#include "secmodi.h"
#include "secmodti.h"
```

I imagine these are files related to libnss3 package. They're not in libnss3-dev package, which has only secmod.h and secmodt.h files. Where can I find these ?
But it would be nice to know how I could find it if I need it again for other files.
I tryied only google and duckgogo as I don't know any specific search engine.

**Edit**

I tried to use dpkg -S, apt-file find and packages.ubuntu.com and couldn't find it. I wonder... could this be an older version of this package or something ?

Comment: What do you mean by "package"? If that refers to Linux packet managers: that has nothing to do with programming at all, as it just reduces to "how to find the package containing a file". For this, read the manpage of your prefered package manager.

Comment: As you may know, in order to compile a certain piece of the code I need these includes. Their respective files are not installed and I don't know where to find them. I guess this has to do with programming.

Comment: In Linux c/c++ include files are organized in packages. We need to know the correct one in order to fulfill the dependencies.

Comment: unzip the package and search for the file inside directory using  *nix command `find <directory> -name  " secmodi.h" `

Comment: Which distribution ? Which package manager are you using ? You usually use the package manager or related tools for that : for instance on Ubuntu (and other Debian based I think) [How do I find the package that provides a file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: There will be a database despite the package manager, with the package name and the files that belong to it. But it's necessary to know which package manager because each has it's own commands.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. So .deb files, and aptitude.

Comment: @Steephen I got these souces from another person and I created a new project for them. Yet I'm trying to debug what whappens in a specific api call to check what parameter is wrong. So I'm replicating api code in application in order to debug it.

Comment: @Leiaz see my edit. I used the answer you provided and couldn't find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the package source. I downloaded it with `sources libnss3-dev`